# Метод принимающий лист интерфейсов, не принимает лист класса, который его реализиует

Tags: c#

```
public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private List<AssetItem> Items;


    private void OnEnable()
    {
        Render( Items); // Ошибка CS1503 Аргумент 1: не удается преобразовать из 
                        //"System.Collections.Generic.List<AssetItem>" в "System.Collections.Generic.List<IItem>
    }

    private void Render(List<IItem> item)
    {
        
    }
}
```

### Реализующий класс

```
public class AssetItem : ScriptableObject, IItem
{
    public string Name => _name;

    public Sprite Icon => _icon;

    [SerializeField] private string _name;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite _icon;
}
```

### Интерфейс

```
public interface IItem
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public Sprite Icon { get;}
}
```

Comment: ну потому что `List<Interface>` и `List<MyClass>` - это разные типы, вот и не принимает.

Comment: Так я в список Предметов пытаюсь засунуть допустим оружие,шмотки и т.д. Это же все предметы и они все реализуют нужный интерфейс. Может я не так вас понял?

Comment: не, вы просто не понимаете разнизу между сравнением типов. Например, если говорить о `interface` и `myclass`, то как бы тут все понятно, `myclass` реализует `interface` и где вы используете `interface`, там же можете подставлять и `myclass`. Но `List<MyClass>` не наследуется от `List<Interface>` - это два разных типа в дотнете. Вы можете один в другой перевести только явно, например как то так `Render( Items.OfType<IItem>().ToList());`

Comment: Спасибо, я попробую

Comment: Ранее задавали этот вопрос, вот: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925400/cast-listt-to-listinterface

Comment: Джон Скит не подведет, всё хорошо пояснил )